# What is the expression " an early ironclad morning" mean?

Tags: expressions

In Sherlock Holmes stories there is an expression somewhere "on one early ironclad morning" what does it mean?

Comment: Which story? The wiktionary concordance does not list "ironclad" as a word in the Holmes canon. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Concordance:Sherlock_Holmes/I   (I like Boldben's answer, though.)

Answer (score 3):

In the second half of the 19th century an "ironclad" was a naval ship with an iron plate (or iron plated) hull. According to [this wiki page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ironclads_of_the_Royal_Navy) ships referred to as "ironclads" were being built as late as 1888 so the term was common currency for Conon Doyle's readership.

"One early ironclad morning", therefore, would be a metaphor for an overcast morning with a featureless grey sky looking like the grey painted plates of a warship. The connotations of menace and great weight associated with a warship would extend the metaphor.